How to prove the Picard's uniqueness theorem for $x < x_{0}$?
I'm working on proving Picard's uniqueness theorem, which states that the integral equation
$$
y(x) = y_{0} + \int_{x_{0}}^{x} f(s, y(s)) \, ds
$$
has only one solution.
Define
$$
\phi(x) = y_{0} + \int_{x_{0}}^{x} f(s, \phi(s)) \, ds
$$
and
$$
\psi(x) = y_{0} + \int_{x_{0}}^{x} f(s, \psi(s)) \, ds.
$$
Subtracting these gives:
$$
|\phi(x) - \psi(x)| = \left| \int_{x_{0}}^{x} (f(s, \phi(s)) - f(s, \psi(s))) \, ds \right|.
$$
Using the Lipschitz condition on $f$:
$$
|\phi(x) - \psi(x)| \leq L \left| \int_{x_{0}}^{x} |\phi(s) - \psi(s)| \, ds \right|.
$$
Let
$$
\Phi(x) = \int_{x_{0}}^{x} |\phi(s) - \psi(s)| \, ds.
$$
For $x \geq x_{0}$:
$$
\Phi(x) \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \Phi(x) \leq 0 \quad \text{for } x \leq x_{0}.
$$
Differentiating for $x \geq x_{0}$:
$$
\Phi'(x) \leq L \Phi(x).
$$
By Gronwall's inequality, we find
$$
\Phi(x) \leq 0 \quad \text{for } x \geq x_{0},
$$
which implies
$$
\Phi(x) \equiv 0 \quad \text{for } x \geq x_{0}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\phi(x) \equiv \psi(x) \quad \text{for } x \geq x_{0}.
$$
However, I need help proving uniqueness for $x < x_{0}$, where the coefficient before $\Phi(x)$ becomes $-L$, causing Gronwall's inequality to fail.
Question: How can I prove the uniqueness of solutions for $x < x_{0}$?
